# Combining arrays with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a chat widget that works like the facebook chat widget. I am now implementing an infinite loading of messages when i scroll up. The problem I am having now is how to combine the next range of messages to previous one, because currently it replaces the previous range when I call the next range. I have cut my code example for brevity:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.props.getMessages(1) // axios call, returns first range
}

handleScroll(event) {
  //some scroll logic
  this.props.getMessages(2) 
  //axios call, returns 2nd range
  //for simplicity i just call 2 ranges for now
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    messages: state.messages
  };
}

export default function (state = {fetched: false}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'FETCH_MESSAGES_FULFILLED':
          return {...state,
            data: action.payload
          }
      break;
   }
   return state;
}
```

data model:

```
[
        {   
            msg_id: 1,
            to_id: 1,
            from_id: 2,
            message: "Marzipan jelly-o croissant sweet gummies chocolate croissant marzipan. Jujubes soufflé tiramisu halvah chocolate oat cake jelly1"
        },
        {   
            msg_id: 2,
            to_id: 1,
            from_id: 2,
            message: "Jelly sw2"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to append messages to the data rather than replace it. You can simple do it with the spread operator syntax like

```
var initialState = {
    fetched: false,
    data: []
}
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'FETCH_MESSAGES_FULFILLED':
          return {...state,
            data: [...state.data, action.payload]
          }
      break;
   }
   return state;
}
```

This is assuming `data` to be an array.

Comment: It doesn't pull up the data for some reason i edited my question to show my data model

Comment: You don't have `data` in your initial `state` so the spread will fail.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for the suggesstion. Updated the answer